# Error while requiring gulp-tslint

Tags: gulp, tslint

I am following Learning Typescript Book and created the following gulpfile.js file :->

```
var tslint      = require('gulp-tslint');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
var tsTestProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('ts-lint', function(){
      return gulp.src(['./source/ts/**/**.ts', './test/**/**.test.ts'])
     .pipe(tslint())
     .pipe(tslint.report('verbose'));
});
gulp.task('default', ['ts-lint']);
```

when I run gulp getting below error :

```
module.js:340
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'tslint'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Files/TypeScript/Packt/LearningTS/node_modules/gulp-
     tslint/index.js:5:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)

"gulp-tslint": "^7.1.0" -> version
```

Can anybody let me know why am I getting this error?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. tslint itself was not installed.

Installed tslint using sudo npm install tslint@>=4.0.0-dev --save-dev

It started working :)